# Getting singleton instance for sublist

Tags: haskell

With package [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) we have a class SingI and instances for type-level List:

```
instance SingI '[]
instance forall a (n1 :: a) (n2 :: [a]).
     (SingI n1, SingI n2) => SingI (n1 : n2)
```

It seems that having SingI constraint for list we can get somehow the same constraint for sublist. So I want to find a way to do it.

I.e. I need something like function

```
f1 :: Sing (ns :: [Symbol]) -> Proxy (xs :: [Symbol]) -> Sing (ns :\\ xs)
```

or

```
f2 :: Sing (ns :: [Symbol]) -> Proxy (xs :: [Symbol]) -> Sing (Intersect ns xs)
```

Which ways do I have to do that?

Comment: What are `:\\ ` and `Intersect`? Assuming they are inductive type families, you can write either function by induction. Note that the `SingI` class really shouldn't factor in here at all. Also, if `:\\ ` and `Intersect` are defunctionalized symbols defined by `singletons`, they will almost certainly have value-level variants already, so you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Yes, they are type families from `singletons`. And they have value-level variants. But I _haven't_ `Sing` for the second argument `xs`. From other side, I understand and can prove "by hand" that both `(:\\)` and `Intersect` give me sublist. And I can prove that if list belongs `SingI` for any sublist also. But I don't know how to tell it to compiler and how to get this value for `Sing (sublist)`

Comment: I didn't notice the 2nd arg was `Proxy` and not `Sing`. `Proxy (xs :: [Symbol])` contains no information about which `[Symbol]` that actually is, so you can't do it. In other words, functions with those types are uninhabited. Indeed, you can prove that `SingI xs` from `SingI (x:xs)` but you don't have a `SingI` constraint there. You must change the type to `(SingI xs) => ...`.